# MVC 3 Reverse Engineer DB Then Switch to Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, code-first

I have used EntitFramework before to do codefirst with MVC; however, I have never reverse engineered an existing database to get my models.

So what I'd like to do is reverse engineer the existing DB then switch to codefirst so that changes made to the models will be reflected in the database automagically by the Entity Framework gods. How would I do this, specifically the reverse engineer then the switch to codefirst? Please have mercy if this is poorly worded or w/e I'm very new to MVC still.

Comment: sorry for this, but 1up for your word-creation of "automagically". Hits the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It basically boils down to using tools to autogenerate the POCO classes that represent your domain, then using those classes as the basis for EF Code First and future migrations.

Here's a msdn article outlining the process

- [Code First to an Existing Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse an existing Database by creating an Entity Data Model.

Check the following link. Here is described step by step the how to reverse a database to a CodeFirst approach with all of the navigation properties and required relationships. This scenario is also very useful for those entity relations that CodeFirst cannot resolve by its own and the configuration in not very intuitive.

[Reverse from ModelFirst to CodeFirst](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/02/24/generating-ef-code-first-model-classes-from-an-existing-database.aspx)

Comment: You can also check the Julie Lerman blog. There you can find very useful information and articles about the different approaches of EF.

http://thedatafarm.com/blog/
.
I also suggest you to read some of the Julie Lerman wroted by her. They can save you from many situations like this.